# For an RPG, scaled integer vs decimal?

Tags: c#, floating-point, integer, decimal

Yes, I realize decimal or float has been asked before, and I know their uses and that decimal is precise and float is non-accurate.

In a game I'm working on, I have the player, which has a movement speed of 36 pixel movement per second. I update this about 10 times a second, making it 3.6 each time. I want this to be precise, but decimal takes up 16 bytes (128 bits), which is a lot. If I want to keep the accuracy, should I use integer instead and scale the numbers? Or.. Is float more suitable? Float and Int32 both take up 4 bytes, but an integer doesn't loose any numbers. So shouldn't Integer be more suitable? Then why would anyone ever use float?

*So basically, which one should I use for speed and accuracy? I'm using decimal at the moment. I want to change it before I get into too much detail in the game, or it's going to get harder to make all those changes.*

Comment: I never really thought that 128 bits are a lot, but I guess I'm a big spender when it comes to data.

Comment: Answer your question with science. You're updating every 100 milliseconds. A processor cycle is let's say one nanosecond. So that gives you 100 million cycles in which to perform your calculations. Measure how many cycles it takes you to perform your calculations and then you'll know whether you're over budget or under budget.  None of us here can do this analysis for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

16 Bytes is a lot *compared to other types*. Go with what satisfies your requirement, no premature optimization.

You might also consider using int and interpreting it as x/10, that way the inaccuracy won't accumulate. But only if those 128bits really bug you (which they shouldn't, imho).

Comment: That's what I was thinking about doing. Are there any downsides of using an integer like that? I'm not sure, but since decimal takes up more bytes than integer, I assumed it was slower. If you know, which one is slower?

Comment: I don't think so. The result will definitely be better if you use int instead of float, since int does not rely on the exponential representation internally as the float types do. So, basically, a viable choice.

Comment: Yea, I'll go with integer. Thanks